# Will this font be visible to everyone?

Tags: css

I am trying to use a custom font called BebasNeue Regular, I am planning to put my website online so it shouldn't only be visible on my local pc. I used the following CSS to import the font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:BebasNeue Regular;
    src:url("BebasNeue Regular.ttf");
}

    .text h1 {
        margin:auto;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:15vw;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-family:BebasNeue Regular;
    }
```

Will this font be visible to other people?

Comment: The font-family property can hold several font names as a "fallback" system. If the browser does not support the first font, it tries the next font. So just add a generic family name like `Serif` after your custom font to be sure.

Comment: So if other people have a browser that support it, they will see it? even if they dont have the .ttf on their pc? could you show me how I can use a google font for a fallback in my code?

Answer (score 0):

@Tommy O is correct about the "fallback" system.  If you you only have the `ttf` version, you should use [Online Font Converter](https://onlinefontconverter.com/) to create the font-files with the desired formats.  The final product will also give you a sample css file that shows you how to apply them properly.  In your case, it would look like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'BebasNeue Regular';
    src: url('BebasNeue Regular.eot');
    src: url('BebasNeue Regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('BebasNeue Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('BebasNeue Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) For font names that have a space in them, use quotes:

```
@font-face {
  font-family:"BebasNeue Regular";
  src:url("BebasNeue Regular.ttf");
}

.text h1 {
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:15vw;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:"BebasNeue Regular";
}
```

But I actually doubt that the ttf file of the font has a space in its name (as you wrote it above), so you better check that, and if it *does*, replace the space (in the filename) with an underscroe, like `BebasNeue_Regular.ttf`.

2.) This code will only work if the font file is in the same directory (on the server) as your html or php file (i.e. the webpage itself).